# Use HC-06 Bluetooth Chip With PIC16F887?

Tags: assembly, bluetooth, pic

Is it possible to use a [HC-06 Bluetooth to UART Converter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B014CX7Z1W) (CSR BC417 Bluetooth chip) with a Microchip PIC16F887 chip?

I am looking at this for a class project. I have to use assembly to program my PIC chip. I intend to write a simple android app to send the PIC commands.

Comment: Should be possible. I used this module successfully on Arduinos and it worked perfectly. The setup is very easy (you might need to add a voltage divider since the module runs generally on 3.3V but not doing so did not break the module in short term). Since your chip has a serial interface (RX/TX) it should l work. (as comment because not tested by myself).

Answer (score -1):

i have wrote some code, may be it would help you,
https://github.com/krishnachaitanya9/Bluetooth-Chat-Android

you need to make some changes in it in order to work, in BluetoothChatService.java file change NAME_SECURE, NAME_INSECURE to hc-06 and MY_UUID_SECURE and MY_UUID_INSECURE to 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB and it should be good to go.